# Changing the font color coming from external link in html

Tags: html, css

I like to change the font color coming from **viewCourseCatalogLinkText** to **white**. The text coming from external link is in **white, black, and blue**. How do I **overwrite** it to make it **white**?

```
<div class="small-12 small-centered text-center columns">
  <c:if test="${ CourseCatalogUtil.getAllowCatalog() }">
    <div id="ultraCourseCatalogLink">
      <a href="file:///C|/Users/vryou/Downloads/${ CourseCatalogUtil.getCatalogUrl( CourseCatalogUtil.getAllowCatalog() ) }" >
        ${viewCourseCatalogLinkText}
      </a>
    </div>
```

I cannot use style properties like this as I don't see the class name

```
div.transbox {
  color:  #ffffff;  
}
```

I tried this as well and did not work

```
 <p class="announcement-text">
          <a href="file:///C|/Users/vryou/Downloads/${ CourseCatalogUtil.getCatalogUrl( CourseCatalogUtil.getAllowCatalog() ) }" style="color: white;">${viewCourseCatalogLinkText}</a>
            </p>
<style>
p.announcement-text
                {
                    color: #ffffff;
                }
</style>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Well I tried to use style properties but I don't see the class name. I added more details to the question.

Comment: Why don't you just give it a class inline and use that class name to access the tag?

Comment: I just did it and did not work, please see my edited question

Comment: Why would you use the selector `div.announcement-text` on a `<p>` element?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it and still wont work. Thanks

Comment: `a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color:#FFF; }`

Comment: I pasted the code you gave me in the style section and it did not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You can view the class name by using the dev tools in chrome or any browser that you're using.

Other than that, you can make all links to have white color by using this:

```
a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Where in the code, I use it? Please see my edited question

Comment: add it anywhere in <style> tags or stylesheet

Comment: It did not work

Comment: try this: a * {

Comment: Nothing changed